# How to change the email linked to console.developers.google.com?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-signin

I unintentionally logged into console.developers.google.com with a different email address.

**Now I want to change the email address**.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the other email address to the permissions lists as an Owner and then remove the email address you added unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

yes, we can add the email address as owner in over projects throw following link https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/projectpermissions=projectname , and after add email the send invitation to email, if they accept then they have full permission to access developer console project. don't miss to change projectname with your project original name in above url.